# KD and TTT – any other Esperantizations of global tech abbreviations?

Tags: abbreviations

I know about **KD** (**kompakta disko**) for *CD* and **TTT** (**Tut-Tera Teksaĵo**) for *WWW*.

Are there any other Esperanto versions of global tech abbreviations?

*For example:* DVD, SMS, MMS, USB, URL, LP, TV…

Answer (score 2):

Not really a list of abbreviations (not acronyms; an acronym is an abbreviation pronouncable as one word), but very useful, as it contains also a lot of abbreviations (I found all you examples with the exception of *MMS*) is [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php), containing over 9000 computer terms in Esperanto.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; I’ve corrected the word in question. :-)